# Intersection of hyperplane and 5-cell

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to learn some coordinates in more than $3$ dimensions. And suddenly stumbled into this:

If we say that in a $4$D regular figure (a regular 5-cell) $ABCDE$, a hyperplane cuts it such that it's parallel and equidistant to edge $AB$ and plane $CDE$, then at what points does the hyperplane cut the $4$D figure? Can we say that the points formed will be $\frac{AC}{2}, \frac{AD}{2}, \frac{AE}{2}, \frac{BC}{2}, \frac{BD}{2}, \frac{BE}{2}$ where $\frac{XY}{2}$ means the midpoint of $X, Y$. I am not sure about this but this is just from a pattern I could observe. I cannot think about the $4$ dimensions, so I just followed a pattern from what happens in the analogous $3$D, $2$D, cases.
Now, we can take some equations and matrices and solve it.

To begin with, we can choose the coordinates in the following manner : $A(2,0,0,0), B(0,2,0,0), C(0,0,2,0), D(0,0,0,2), E(\tau, \tau, \tau, \tau)$ where $\tau$ is the golden ratio(from Wikipedia). Since it's a *regular* figure, we can always consider a homothety/dilation to get the figure of the desired shape. So, the above coordinates work. Now, we can carry on from here. But I'm  a not sure how to do that

But I'm not really getting much idea about that.

Comment: Start by defining the unknown quantities to be found.  I'm not getting a clear idea of what "a 4D regular figure" is (possibly a $4$-simplex?).  Then explore what equations those unknowns are supposed to satisfy.   If indeed they are linear equations (first-degree polynomial system), then you are close to giving a matrix formulation.

Comment: The [regular 5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell) appears to be the same as a regular 4-simplex.  The illustration there may help you visualize what it would mean for a "hyperplane" (3D) to be parallel to/equidistant from the edge AB and the triangle (plane) CDE.

Comment: The difficult part for you seems to be assigning coordinates in $\mathbb R^4$ to the five vertices of your 5-cell.  It may help to think of time $t$ as your fourth dimension  besides $x,y,z$.  I would begin by rewording the Question to include specific coordinates for the five vertices equally spaced, with edge AB at time $t=-1$ and triangle $CDE$ at time $t=+1$.  The hyperplane that cuts between them is then $t=0$.

Comment: If you edit your Question to include and justify your choice of vertex coordinates, then I will vote to reopen.  Unless the Question is reopened, no one can post an Answer.

Comment: Patterns can be delusive. Equations can't. Write the equation of the (hyper)plane, will you?

Comment: Forget the "parallel" part, concentrate on the "equidistant". How do we measure a distance from a point to a plane?

Comment: Forget Lagrange multipliers. OK, you have the distance formula. Plug the coordinates of the five points that you have. Equate the distances. Oh, and here's a hint for you: remove the modulo, and you'll have the ***signed*** distance (one that notices which side of the plane are you on). Two points are on one side, three are on the other.

Comment: You have the distance to the hyperplane. That's enough; you don't need any other kind of distance. Just equate the distances and see where this gets you. As for your "what if", well, you may try that too, if you know how to do it; otherwise you can't.

Comment: Good. Now, by "equate" I mean this: write one distance, then the equals sign (=), then another distance. Pay attention to the signs (two of them must be opposite to the three others, remember). Simplify whatever possible. See where this gets you.

Comment: Well, this makes a system of four linear equations with five variables. You should be able to get the variables up to proportionality. (And yes, don't forget to revert the signs for two distances.)

Comment: $a=b$ is an equation. So is $b=c$. How many equations do you have? How many unknowns are in those equations?

Comment: Yes you do know, you've said it yourself: A and B are on one side, and the rest are on the other. So it is more like $AH=BH=-CH=-DH=-EH$ (if you use the _signed_ distance, that is), and if you count the equals signs, you will see there are **four** of them, hence four equations.

Comment: Yes, that too.$\!$

Comment: @user533051 Why did you delete this post, now undeleted by others?

Comment: There has also been a claim that this question is from an ongoing contest and thus violates our policy. We need the flagger (or anyone else) to provide a link to the contest (as a comment or in a free form flag). This is because we want to be able to verify such claims.

Comment: Indeed, this is too close to Problem 5 from [Mathcamp Qual quiz, 2018](http://www.mathcamp.org/prospectiveapplicants/quiz/index.php). I am deleting the answer, and locking the question for the duration of the contest. I have been told that Mathcamp organizers have no problems identifying an applicant who produces a solution copied from the internet. Anyway, if anyone associated with Mathcamp wants to see the solution proposed here (for the purposes of identifying the cheater), please flag this post or @-ping me, and I will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working in four dimensional Euclidean space, where points are identified by four real coordinates, say $(x,y,z,t)$.  It may help with "visualization" to think of the fourth coordinate at time, so that increasing it amounts to shifting a figure forward in time, etc.

Let's choose the coordinates in a way that makes the intersecting hyperplane as simple as the hyperplane $t=0$, a three dimensional subspace.

To do this place the edge $AB$ and the triangle $CDE$ at equal but opposing distances from the hyperplane, so that $t=0$ is halfway between them.  For simplicity we set the $t$-coordinates of $A,B$ to $1$ and set the $t$-coordinates of $C,D,E$ to $-1$. The six edges that connect vertices $A,B$ to vertices $C,D,E$ will thus be bisected by hyperplane $t=0$.

The regularity of the figure means that its five vertex points are equidistant from one another.  The triangle $CDE$ will be equilateral, and its three edges will have the same lengths as the edge $AB$.

Center the equilateral triangle $CDE$ around $(0,0,0,-1)$ in the plane $z=0,t=-1$, and center the edge $AB$ on the point $(0,0,0,1)$ so it can be rotated in the $x,y$-coordinates without changing distances to the points $C,D,E$.  To be specific, let:

$$ A = (0,0,+b,1) $$

$$ B = (0,0,-b,1) $$

$$ C = (a,0,0,-1) $$

$$ D = (-a/2,a\sqrt{3}/2,0,-1) $$

$$ E = (-a/2,-a\sqrt{3}/2,0,-1) $$

Now the length of any of the edges from $A$ or $B$ to one of $C,D,E$ is:

$$ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 4} $$

while the length of $AB$ is:

$$ \sqrt{4b^2} $$

and the length of any side of $CDE$ is:

$$ \sqrt{3a^2} $$

Solving for $a,b$ that make the three quantities above equal gives:

$$ a = \frac{4}{5} \sqrt{5} $$

$$ b = \frac{2}{5} \sqrt{15} $$

It remains only to find the midpoints of the edges $AC,AD,AE,BC,BD,BE$ (where $t=0$) and connect them (as corners of the three dimensional figure formed by the intersection of the 5-cell and the hyperplane) accordingly as midpoints are connected in triangles $ACD,ADE,AEC,BCD,BDE,BEC$ and $ABC,ABD,ABE$.

Although details of the vertex coordinates remain to be worked out, the outline of the figure already comes into focus.  With nine edges and six vertices, [Euler's polyhedron formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra) tells us there are five faces.  This means the polyhedron is a [triangular prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism).

Comment: I didn't get the last part of your write-up. Why did you cite so many triangles and edges at the end?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "hyperplane $t=0$? What would be the equation of the hyperplane in that case?

Comment: Umm, the equation would be $t=0$.  That makes "visualizing" the hyperplane easy, and motivates putting the triangle and the edge at equal "times" before and after the moment $t=0$.  You realize that self-deleting your Question after you get an Answer is likely to make Readers reluctant to help, don't you?

Comment: The reason for citing the triangles and edges *in four dimensions* at the end of my Answer is that their intersections with the hyperplane (a three dimensional subspace) gives us respectively the *edges* and *vertices* of the figure you are asking about (intersection of hyperplane and 5-cell, a convex three dimensional solid polyhedron).

Comment: Let's say the equation of the hyperplane is $ax+by+cz+dt+e=0$, then, how do you write the equation? Will it be $ax+by+cz+e=0$? What about the $a,b,c?$ Can you please come over this? (And please forget about the deletion; I was about to edit the post and it got deleted and I couldn't revert it back. Apologies for that. I'm not too old here in this site)

Comment: Also, how do you take the parallel condition under consideration?

Comment: The equation $t=0$ is the same as $0x+0y+0z+1t+0 = 0$, but we often prefer the shorter form for its clarity.  A point $(x,y,z,t)$ belongs to this hyperplane if and only if $t=0$.  In the Question you write that the hyperplane is "parallel and equidistant" from the edge $AB$ and the triangle $CDE$.  The notion of an edge being parallel to a hyperplane is best interpreted as both endpoints are the same distance from the hyperplane.  That does not give a unique hyperplane, as pointed out in comments.

Comment: That doesn't give a unique hyperplane. You mean, one on the postive side and the other on the negative? (Considering the signed distance)

Comment: That doesn't give a unique hyperplane. You mean, one on the postive side and the other on the negative? (Considering the signed distance)

Comment: You need to understand how to find the distance from a point to a hyperplane.  The (signed) distance from a point $(p,q,r,s)$ to the hyperplane $t=0$ is $s$.  By analogy with the normal form of an equation of a line (in the $x,y$-plane) and the distance from a point to that line, we can put the equation of a hyperplane into "normal form".  The equation $t=0$ is already in normal form, and the signed distance from a point to that hyperplane is just the $t$-coordinate of the point.